# where is bin directory in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am trying to place the `wkhtmltopdf` executable in the "bin directory" of my rails project so that it works with heroku, as mentioned [here](http://blog.mattgornick.com/using-pdfkit-on-heroku).

dumb question....where is the "bin" folder in the rails project? I placed the executable in `root` of my executable, however, heroku gives an error saying:

```
No wkhtmltopdf executable found at /app/bin/wkhtmltopdf-i386
```

And the following code is used to provide path for wkhtmltopdf

```
config.wkhtmltopdf = Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf-i386');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create the bin folder under the app/ folder and add it in there.

```
mkdir app/bin
```

Comment: it should be under the root. `~/your_project/bin` not `~/your_project/app/bin`  Thanks for letting me know that it needs to be created though :)

Comment: Glad I could help. I should have payed more attention to the second part I was answer based on where it was looking at the 'no executable found' section. Glad it is working :)