# rails not creating bin folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bin

New Rails user here. Apologies if this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find it after a day of searching.

I was following the Ruby on Rails [getting started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), so I created a test app called blog. According to the tutorial, the blog directory should have a bin folder in it, but it does not. It contains all of the other folders listed on the tutorial page, plus one called "scripts". Is scripts essentially the same folder as bin, or am I missing something? I am running rails v. 3.2.13 from a windows command prompt.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bin directory was introduced in Rails 4.0

**http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html**

6.1 Notable changes
Your app's executables now live in the bin/ directory. Run rake rails:update:bin to get bin/bundle, bin/rails, and bin/rake.

Answer (score 8):

In case of **Rails 5.2**  you will have to run **rake app:update:bin** command to create bin folder.

i.e.

```
 rake app:update:bin
```

It will show you output like below:

```
  create  bin
  create  bin/bundle
  create  bin/rails
  create  bin/rake
  create  bin/setup
  create  bin/update
  create  bin/yarn
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to run `rake rails:update:bin` to create and populate the bin folder for Rails 4+

Answer (score 0):

[where is bin directory in rails3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922870/where-is-bin-directory-in-rails3)

> You need to create the bin folder under the app/ folder and add it in
>   there.
>
> ```
> mkdir app/bin
> ```